# Avoid repeating statements when importing data

Tags: r, loops, import

Iv'e written the following code to import data into R:

```
## specify where all the data files are stored 
DataFolder <- "DataFolder"

## obtain the name of each file in DataFolder
files <- list.files(DataFolder)

## obtain name of each file
LocNames <- unique(sub("^([^.]*).*", "\\1", files)) # this removes the extension and keeps the unique names

for (i in 1:length(LocNames)){

  #
  car <- read.table(paste(DataFolder, paste(LocNames[i], ".car", sep=""), sep="/"),
                    header = TRUE, sep = "\t", colClasses=c(dateTime="POSIXct"))  
  car <- aggregate(car[colnames(car)[2:length(colnames(car))]],list(dateTime = cut(car$dateTime,breaks = "hour")),mean, na.rm = TRUE)

  #  
  light <- read.table(paste(DataFolder, paste(LocNames[i], ".light", sep=""), sep="/"),
                    header = TRUE, sep = "\t", colClasses=c(dateTime="POSIXct"))
  light <- aggregate(light[colnames(light)[2]],list(dateTime = cut(light$dateTime, breaks = "hour")),mean, na.rm = TRUE)
}
```

So, here I have a DataFolder where all of my files are stored. The files are named according to the location where the data was recorded and the extension of the file given the name of the variable measured. Here we have car sales and light as examples.

From here I would like to reduce the size of the arguments inside of the loop so instead of having to name one variable after the other repeating the same steps I want to only have to write the variable name e.g. car, light and then the outcome of the script shown will be returned.

Please let me know if my intentions have not been clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a function. Something to the effect of

```
## specify where all the data files are stored 
DataFolder <- "DataFolder"

## obtain the name of each file in DataFolder
files <- list.files(DataFolder)

readMyFiles <- function(DataFolder, LocNames, extension){
  data <- read.table(paste(DataFolder, paste(LocNames[i], ".", extension, sep=""), sep="/"),
                    header = TRUE, sep = "\t", colClasses=c(dateTime="POSIXct"))  
  data <- aggregate(data[colnames(data)[2:length(colnames(data))]],list(dateTime = cut(data$dateTime,breaks = "hour")),mean, na.rm = TRUE)
  data
}

## obtain name of each file
LocNames <- unique(sub("^([^.]*).*", "\\1", files)) # this removes the extension and keeps the unique names

for (i in 1:length(LocNames)){

  car <- readMyFiles(DataFolder, LocNames, ".car")

  light <- readMyFiles(DataFolder, LocNames, ".light")
}
```